# Using Bootstrap Accordion Panels

Tags: xpages

Been struggling with jQuery syntax. I am trying to setup some JS code to expand/collapse an accordion panel (http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp). I can get it to expand and collapse with x$("#{id:collapsePanel2}").collapse("toggle");  That works fine but does not collapse the other panels. You can see this at https://www.netexperts.com/xpages1.nsf/collapse.xsp. There is a "parent" parameter which says it takes the selector. I have tried "#view:_id1:accordion" (the generated id of the parent panel), I have tried parent="#view:_id1:accordion" and a few other combinations. The docs at http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp  under the .collapse options say the parent is a parameter that takes the parent selector but I can't seem to pass this in without throwing a JS error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xe:navbar
    id="navbar1"
    headingText="Collapse Panel"
    pageWidth="full">
</xe:navbar>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>

<xp:panel
    styleClass="panel-group"
    id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <xp:link
                    escape="true"
                    id="link1">
                    Collapsible panel

                    <xp:eventHandler
                        event="onclick"
                        submit="false">
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
//function is called using x$("#{id:inputText1}", " parameters").
x$("#{id:collapsePanel}").collapse( "toggle"); 
function x$(idTag, param){ //Updated 18 Feb 2012
 idTag=idTag.replace(/:/gi, "\\:")+(param ? param : "");
 return($("#"+idTag));
}

]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:link>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <xp:panel
            id="collapsePanel"
            styleClass="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </xp:panel>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <xp:link
                    escape="true"
                    id="link2">
                    Collapsible panel

                    <xp:eventHandler
                        event="onclick"
                        submit="false">
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
//function is called using x$("#{id:inputText1}", " parameters").
x$("#{id:collapsePanel2}").collapse("toggle"); 
function x$(idTag, param){ //Updated 18 Feb 2012
  idTag=idTag.replace(/:/gi, "\\:")+(param ? param : "");
  return($("#"+idTag));
}

]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:link>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <xp:panel
            id="collapsePanel2"
            styleClass="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </xp:panel>
    </div>
</xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the jquery something like this

```
$( "#link" ).on( "click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#accordion .panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('#collapseTwo').collapse('toggle');
});
```

Working example http://bootsbin.com/bin/view/46/

Comment: Thanks, but wanted to use the parent parameter which should collapse the other panels automatically per the docs at http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp